# Solving integral equation for a measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

For a given $a \in \mathbb R_{+}^*$, can we find a (positive) measure $\nu$ with support included in $\mathbb R$ such that, $\forall t \in \mathbb R_+^*$, $$at^2 = \int\limits_{\mathbb R} \ln\left(\frac{x}{x+t}\right) \partial\nu(x)\text{ ?}$$

I have no clue where to start, or if it is even doable. My first guess was to suppose that $\nu(\mathbb R) < \infty$, let $b = a\nu(\mathbb R)$ and try to solve instead $$bt^2 = \mathbb E\left(\ln(X)\right) - \mathbb E\left(\ln(X +t)\right)$$ for a random variable $X$, but i had no more sucess :)

Comment: Let's assume $d\nu(x) = f(x)\,dx$ (i.e. $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure - other choices are a bit more pathological). We probably want $f$ to be supported on the positive half line to avoid domain of definition issues for $\log$. To that end, we may as well assume we are integrating over the half line anyway. So we wish to solve

$$ at^2 = \int_{\Bbb R^+} \log\left(\frac{x}{x+t}\right)f(x)\,dx. $$

Comment: Taking some liberties, let's assume we can take derivatives and push them around as we see fit. Then

$$ 2at = \int_{\Bbb R^+} \frac{x+t}{x} \left(-\frac{x}{(x+t)^2}\right) f(x)\,dx = - \int_{\Bbb R^+} \frac{1}{x+t} f(x)\,dx. $$

The quantity on the left hand side is positive whereas the quantity on the right hand side is negative. This suggests that whatever solution might exist is probably very pathological that Lebesgue dominated convergence doesn't even apply.